# R - how to vectorize computation of sum of outer products, when vectors are in two matrices?

Tags: r, vectorization

R - how to vectorize computation of sum of outer products, when vectors are in two matrices - `X` and `Y` ?

**Example :**

```
X = cbind(1:3, 2:4)
Y = cbind(0:2, c(0,0,1))
> X
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    3    4
> Y
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    1    0
[3,]    2    1

> outer(X[1,],Y[1,]) + outer(X[2,],Y[2,]) + outer(X[3,],Y[3,])
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    8    3
[2,]   11    4
```

I would like to vectorize operation :

`outer(X[1,],Y[1,]) + outer(X[2,],Y[2,]) + outer(X[3,],Y[3,])` - is it possible ? Mayby something with general construction like : `lapply( ,FUN=outer)`, and then taking sum of elements in list ? Otherwise I have to loop over `outer(X[i,],Y[i,])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just `matrix multiplication`:

```
t(X) %*% Y
v     [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    8    3
# [2,]   11    4
```

You need a 2*2 matrix and both matrices X and Y are of dimensons 3*2. Transposing X gives 2*3 and when multiplied with 3*2 matrix gives the desired 2*2 matrix.